Adding an icon in google search results
where do I need to code on my website to show the little 20 x 20 icon that appears in google search results ? I do have a Site Icon which is what you see in browser tabs, bookmark bars, and within the WordPress mobile apps. Please see the image below to see what I mean.


The description from google: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search.

you need to set a favicon for your website and after sometime google shows your favicon or site icon next to your site name.
A favicon image is displayed to the left of the page title in the browser tab
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">

you can read more about it here
readmore
